# "React.createContext is not a function" only when I use emotion/styled and @testing-library/react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, emotion

I am using `emotion/styled` with Next.js and TypeScript. It works well on `yarn dev`. CSS/HTML also works well, but when I'm testing with `@testing-library/react` it returns an error:

> "React.createContext is not a function"

I was searching on Google this error and I found it's a module version crash problem so I deleted `node_modules` and reinstalled the modules, but it still returns an error.

I think this error is related to the emotion library because it only happens when the emotion library is used.